# Separately continuous functions that are discontinuous at every point

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

What are some good examples of separately continuous functions $f: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ that are discontinuous at every point?

Here's a theorem to rule out some spaces: [link for a reference](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102912474)

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be locally compact or completely metrizable, $Y$ compact Hausdorff, $Z$ a metric space. If $f: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ is separately continuous, then there exists a dense $G_\delta$ subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f$ is continuous on $A \times Y$.

So no example exists for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ satisfying the assumptions of the theorem.

Comment: By separately continuous do you mean that when fixing $x$, the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous from $Y$ to $Z$, and similarly for fixing $y$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes.

Comment: What kind of spaces do you want to consider? No such $f$ exists if $X,Y,Z$ are metrizable.

Comment: @Martin: Are you sure? It seems, there is no such $f$ provided some spaces have some "complete" properties.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you're right. I should have said *completely* metrizable ($X$ and $Y$ complete should be enough). There always is a comeager set on which $f$ is continuous, but that might be empty without assuming some completeness.

Comment: There should be a lot of such examples in the papers by V. K. Maslyuchenko and his son, O. V. Maslyuchenko. They both are powerful mathematicians and have a family “tradition” or, even, a school, devoted to different weak continuity of maps on the products of different topological spaces. :-) So I suggest you to search and to look their papers devoted to separately continuous not (joint) continuous maps.

Comment: @Martin: Any topological spaces. See my edit

Comment: @spin: If any spaces can satisfy you, you may take $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$ in the cofinite topology (that is, a nonempty set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open iff $\mathbb{R}\backslash A$ is finite) and $f(x,y)=x+y$ for each $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. :-)

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Thanks, that's a very simple example. I believe it should work even when we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any infinite abelian group.

Comment: It seems so for any infinite group $G$, since for each cofinite subsets $U,V$ of $G$ we have that $UV=G$, therefore the multiplication on $G\times G$ maps each nonempty open set onto the whole $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering so that this isn't unanswered. In the comments, Alex Ravsky suggested the following example which was just what I needed.

Consider any infinite group $G$ equipped with the cofinite topology. Then the multiplication map $G \times G \rightarrow G$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ is separately continuous everywhere, but is not jointly continuous at any point.