# a theorem of Baire dissertation

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation, baire-category

A function of two variables continues at each variable doesn't have to be continuous but it is pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. In all articles and books that I search for a proof of this statement there is no proof available all saying it is well known that... (with a reference to Baire dissertation more than a century ago). Does some one know any source /book for easy undergraduate based proof?

Comment: Is this function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? ... or more general?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019208/separately-continuous-functions-f-mathbbr2-rightarrow-mathbbr-but-now

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, *It is well-known that in this case the set of points of discontinuity is of the first category.* like any other places!

Comment: @LiebeGreen That part is not needed to show that a function separately continuous is a limit of continuous functions, it is only needed to show that a separately continuous function is continuous on a big set, but that was not part of your question. In any case I wrote down a short proof of that result which is claimed but not proved in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that any function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ separately continuous is of Baire class one (pointwise limit of continuous functions) see the argument given in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019208/separately-continuous-functions-f-mathbbr2-rightarrow-mathbbr-but-now).

They are assuming the well known fact that every function of Baire class one is continuous on a comeagre set without proof (note that it isn't needed to answer your question about writing a separately continuous function as a limit of continuous ones), but that is the easy part:

**Theorem:** let $X,Y$ be metrizable spaces with $Y$ separable and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be of Baire class one. Then $f$ is continuous on a comeagre $G_\delta$ set.

**Proof:** Fix a countable open basis $\{V_n\}$ of $Y$ and note that $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ if an only if there is $n$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(V_n)\setminus\mathrm{int}(f^{-1}(V_n))$. In other words the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ is $$\bigcup_n f^{-1}(V_n)\setminus\mathrm{int}(f^{-1}(V_n)).$$
Now $f^{-1}(V_n)$ is $F_\sigma$ and so is $f^{-1}(V_n)\setminus\mathrm{int}(f^{-1}(V_n))$, so write it as $\bigcup_k F_{n,k}$ with $F_{n,k}$ closed for all $k$. Clearly each $F_{n,k}$ has empty interior, and hence the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ can be written as $\bigcup_n\bigcup_k F_{n,k}$, which is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, as we wanted to show.