# Does holomorphicness of left and right multiplication imply holomorphicness of multiplication?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $G$ be a complex group, i.e. a complex manifold with a group structure. Assume that for each $g\in G$, the map
$$G\rightarrow G,h\mapsto gh^{-1}$$
is holomorphic. Can it imply that $G$ is a complex Lie group? Or equivlently, is the map
$$G\times G\rightarrow G,(g,h)\mapsto gh^{-1}$$
also holomorphic?

Link to [Does smoothness of left and right multiplication imply smoothness of multiplication?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120965/does-smoothness-of-left-and-right-multiplication-imply-smoothness-of-multiplicat)